# Getting value of ID from class

Tags: google-analytics

How is it possible to get the value of ID from class using google tag manager?

```
<html>
    <body>
        <textarea id='5' class='cp _check'>sometexthere</textarea>
    </body>
<html>
```

Using JQuery it is possible with this:

```
$(".cp._check").attr("id")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to variables, select new, type DOM. Select CSS selector. You can then use selectors similarly to jQuery:

[image]

Even though there might be multiple matches for your selector GTM retrieves the value for the first occurence only.

Comment: While this is possible (you'd need to feed to result of the variable above into another DOM variable template to retrieve the element) at this just point it's perhaps simpler to use a custom HTML tag and do this via Javascript.

Comment: Hi Agata, will do later this evening (I'm at work right now and can't do elaborate screenshots).

Comment: Pierstoff please take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31732017/taking-the-pageviews-of-urls

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should use following code:
$("#cp_check").attr("id")

Answer (score 0):

### Data Uniqueness

This can be unreliable until you cannot be sure that class cp_check is unique.

### Data-attribution way

Rather change id from **5** to **"form-text-field"** (or whatever you want) and your desired value put into **data-id**:

```
<textarea id='form-text-field' data-id='5' class='cp _check'>sometexthere</textarea>
```

And then your jQuery wil looks like:

```
$("#form-text-field").attr("data-id")
```

### Google Tag Manager

1) Create macro type JavaScript:

```
function(){
   var dat = $("#form-text-field").attr("data-id");
   return dat;
}
```

2) Or Create macro type DOM ELEMENT Method -> CSS Selector

- Selector: **.cp_check** (in your example) **#form-text-field** (in this example)
- Attr: **id** (in your example) **data-id** (in thisexample)