# Taking the pageviews of urls

Tags: jquery, google-tag-manager

I have a site and I want to take the pageviews for specific urls using google tag manager and datalayer variables.

Example urls

```
http://www.test.com
http://www.test.com/e-shop
http://www.test.com/contact
```

I create datalayer variables with 
home
eshop
contact

After I set the following trigger using every datalayer variable as custom events

```
home
eshop
contact
```

After that what code should I write in tag I have named it Pageviews in order to have this variables in google analytics?

Is there any easier way to make it but again using datalayer?

Comment: You want to trigger the goal through JS using the datalayer? Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need a custom dataLayer variable for this. I would do it this way:

**Create a new Tag**

1. Product: Google Analytics
2. Tag Type: Universal Analytics
3. Configuration:

   - Track Type: Page View
   - Tracking ID: your Tracking ID
4. Fire on:

   - Some Pages

In the overlay popping up on step 4, add 3 new triggers as follows

```
| Name     | Variable     | Operation     | Value     |  
| Home     | Page Path    | equals        | /         |  
| E-Shop   | Page Path    | equals        | e-shop    |  
| Contact  | Page Path    | equals        | contact   |
```

Save and test your new tag in preview mode. This setup will use the `event` dataLayer variable behind the scene, which sends a "Page View" event by default.