# How do I display a unique id value with GTM?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-tag-manager

I have multiple elements on a page with the same class name, but each element has a unique id name.

Example:

```
<div class="video-image" id="get-googled">
<div class="video-image" id="email-marketing">
```

I want to display the id value, but right now I am only able to have GTM return and display the first element on the page. I read this post: "[Getting value of ID from class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31430820/getting-value-of-id-from-class/31431330#31431330)" and it didn't help and even explains doing it the simple way will only display the first elements value.

Do I need custom Javascript to create this properly?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a specific div and you know where it is on the page you might be able to use a DOM variable with an [nth of type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) query selector. But this seems cumbersome, and since it seems you want a list in any case I think you are better of with a custom javascript variable:

```
function() {
  return document.querySelectorAll(".video-image");
}
```

which return a collection of DOM elements (you might want to check if there are actually  elements with that class first).

Comment: I"m not sure I understand. I don't want a "list" I am setting up custom event tracking. The events will then be tracked and displayed through GA. All this Javascript returns for me is  "[object NodeList]"

Answer (score 0):

The initial answer is the right start - this completes the loop:

```
    <script>
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".video-image");
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
      alert(inputs[i].id);
    }
    </script>

Here is a JSFiddle to try it out - [https://jsfiddle.net/JMurphy22/kduybmsp/2/][1]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).